# Cleared and re-printed output in shell is flashing

Tags: rust, io, stdout

I'm trying to learn rust and wrote a small program. The program is supposed to take a matrix of random variables, convert them to chars and print them to stdout over and over again.

The code itself is running fine, but the output keeps flashing -- as if for a millisecond, something isn't printed properly. I recorded a video that shows the flashing:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DaVzKSuXUjg

The code is as follows:

```
use std::io;
use std::io::Write;
use std::thread::sleep;
use std::time::Duration;

use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    let mut image: [[f32; 30]; 30] = [[0.0; 30]; 30];

    loop {
        let x = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0..30);
        let y = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(0..30);
        let value: f32 = rand::thread_rng().gen();
        image[x][y] = value;
        display(&image).expect("Can't display the image!");
        sleep(Duration::new(0, 10_000_000));
    }
}

fn display(image: &[[f32; 30]; 30]) -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut pixel_matrix = String::from("\x1B[2J\x1B[1;1H"); // reset cursor to 1,1
    for x in 0..image.len() {
        for y in 0..image[x].len() {
            let value = image[x][y];
            pixel_matrix.push(
                match value {
                    x if (0.0..0.1).contains(&x) => ' ',
                    x if (0.1..0.2).contains(&x) => '.',
                    x if (0.2..0.3).contains(&x) => ':',
                    x if (0.3..0.4).contains(&x) => '-',
                    x if (0.4..0.5).contains(&x) => '=',
                    x if (0.5..0.6).contains(&x) => '+',
                    x if (0.6..0.7).contains(&x) => '*',
                    x if (0.7..0.8).contains(&x) => '#',
                    x if (0.8..0.9).contains(&x) => '%',
                    x if (0.9..1.0).contains(&x) => '@',
                    _ => ' ',
                }
            );
        }
        pixel_matrix.push('\n');
        let mut stdout = io::stdout().lock();
        stdout.write_all(pixel_matrix.as_bytes()).expect("Can't write to stdout!");

    }
    Ok(())
}
```

What is causing the flashes?
Is the code too fast and re-renders too early? Is something up with the terminal emulator?

Comment: Hello, you make an infinite loop and call `display` each time, every 0.01 second. Is flashing because at each call of `display` `image` is not the same.

Comment: @Zeppi I _want_ the image to change every 0.01 seconds. In the video it is clearly visible that sometimes it changes smoothly on the screen, sometimes the screen flashes black.
It does _not_ flash every 0.01 seconds, this is not the issue!

Comment: When you are learning, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is great to get an overall review of your code. There are several things you could improve.

Comment: A ok, so, It is perhaps an client side stdout effect. could you try with a matrice more lite, 3x3 for exemple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by you having `stdout.write_all` for every line.

You basically add line by line the new image and then sleep for 10ms.
Sometimes you programm is fast enough that while the new lines come in the terminal is not rendering them, sometimes the terminal is rendering.

I think what you want is to have your `stdout.write_all` outisde of the for loop  in the line just above `Ok(())`